# angular-ui/ui-calendar: Display event information with mouseover

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[On the demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/),  I saw that the event name was popped up when the day was hovered.
I've been searching the documentation, but I don't see any description as to how to make it happen.

I suppose the event name would be displayed with `mouseover` and changing something in `uiConfig`.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a built-in feature in `ui-calendar`.

[The demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) uses the [tooltip component of UI Bootstrap for Angular](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) to display event information. You need to:

- add `ui.bootstrap` to your module:

  ```
  angular.module('yourAp', ['ui.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap']);
  ```
- configure the calendar to display a tooltip for every event:

  ```
  $scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
      // This enables the tooltip for every event
      eventRender: function( event, element, view ) {
          element.attr({'tooltip': event.title,
                'tooltip-append-to-body': true});
          $compile(element)($scope);
      };
    }
  };
  ```

Obviously, you may use the `eventRender` hook to add different behavior/UI elements.

**EDIT FROM THE POSTER**

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar:{
    eventRender: function( event, element, view ) {
        element.attr({ 
            "tooltip-placement":"top", 
            "uib-tooltip": event.title, 
            "tooltip-append-to-body": true 
        });
        $compile(element)($scope);
    };
  }
};
```

Apparently, the version of my Angular and that of Tooltip were inconsistent. The code above solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way, could you please adding something in this answer for other people?

Comment: element.attr({
          "tooltip-placement":"top",
          "uib-tooltip":  event.title,
          "tooltip-append-to-body": true
        });

Comment: Apperantly my AngularJs and tooltip versions were not consistent, so I had to make `element` look like this

Comment: @YMD You mean a jsFiddle link?

Comment: You should be careful with putting that in there, that is going to be triggered more than once per event if you have like 30 events. So you will end up compiling more than once that thing